# python regex remove all consecutive duplicates EXCEPT www

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I have strings like this

```
wwwccccheapflightscom 
aaaamypage
wwwregularexpressions
```

Right now I have this, which removes all consecutive dups of length greater than 3.

```
re.sub(r"(\w)\1{2,}",'', string)
```

But I don't want it to remove "www" and I want also to KEEP the first occurrence of the consecutive digits. So based on the example, I want

```
wwwcheapflightscom 
amypage
wwwregularexpressions
```

Comment: I wonder what is the expected result for `wwwwccccheapflightscom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Negative Lookahead for `www` e.g. `(?!www)` at the beginning of your code:

```
(?!www)(\w)\1{2,}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kXBAgV/1

If you want to keep the the first occurrence, substitute with `\1` as suggested by @bobblebubble

bobble's Demo: https://www.regex101.com/r/4bjQlu/1

.

Alternatively, you can use Positive Lookbehind `(?<=)`.

> Note: This will not work in Python, but it will work in PHP,

```
(?<=(\w)|(www\w))(?:\w)\1{2,}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kXBAgV/3

Comment: What do i do if i I want to keep the first Ocurrance? The solution you gave removes the first occurance.

For example 

wwwcccaribeancheapcom

I want it wwwcaribeancheapcom instead of wwwaribeancheapcom

Comment: @Ibrahim I think the lookbehind solution [might not work with Python regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/NkquBV/1) (why I mention to subst  to`\1`).

Comment: Thank you @bobblebubble +1. I updated my answer to reflect your feedback